# Where can I get a RSS feed for stock markets?

Tags: rss, stock, stocks, stockquotes

I am creating a website where people can type in the name of the company and see it's latest stock prices. Where can I get a realtime stock RSS feed? Do I have to pay for it?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 3):

There are API-based stock tickers you can use. I would look for something like that instead of an RSS feed. [Yahoo! has a stock info REST API that looks usable for this](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/). [UPDATE: Yahoo! no longer has that REST API. But you get the idea.]

RSS would be a poor format for a stock feed. You would have thousands upon thousands of pieces of data to be updated every few minutes if not more frequently. And to be used as a ticker, everyone using it would have to load the RSS feed every few minutes at least. That's a lot of data to pull down and expire and pull down and process and expire and....

I doubt this exists. And if it does, I doubt it is free. And if it is, I doubt it will be useful in your app.

Answer (score 0):

http://download.cnet.com/Desktop-Ticker/3000-2164_4-10968747.html

then go to the NAZ page and get their RSS data link... 10 symbol limit, free

Answer (score 0):

Visit NASDAQ at https://www.nasdaq.com/services/rss.aspx and input up to ten stock market symbols you want to track, each separated by a space or comma. Click "Generate feed URL" and then you can use the link it provides you with as an RSS feed. Dow Jones RSS feeds are available at https://us.spindices.com/rss/. All these are free. The MarketWatch RSS feeds (see https://www.marketwatch.com/rss/) specifically state, however, that "The feeds are free of charge for use by individuals, as long as the feeds are used for such individual’s personal, non-commercial use."